# Why does SIGUSR1 terminate my child process although signal() function has been used?

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have the following code:

```
void sig_handler(int sig) {
    printf("Hello child\n");
}

int main()
{
    pid_t child = fork();
    if (child > 0)
    {
        printf("Hello parent\n");
        kill(child, SIGUSR1);
    }
    else if (child == 0)
    {
        signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);
        printf("In child\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want the code to run:

```
Hello parent
Hello child
In child
```

But the child is killed immediately after the parent sends `kill(child, SIGUSR1);`, and the result is just:

```
Hello parent
```

I have read document that the dafault action of the `SIGUSR1` is termination, however, I have already implemented the signal handler `signal(SIGUSR1, sig_handler);` for catching the `SIGUSR1`, then why is the child still killed?

Comment: The signal probably arrives before the signal handler is installed

Comment: @Kninnug Can you explain to me more about the installation of the signal handler?

Comment: You can't safely use `printf()` in a signal handler, btw. See http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say there are two possibilities: either the son process dies before the main process sends the signal, or the main process sends the signal before the handler is set.

Edit: if you only get "Hello parent" it can't be the first one.

Comment: Can you explain to me more about the setting of handler? Because if the first possibilities happens, it will also print `In child` right? So I think it should be the second possibilities.

Comment: Indeed if you get only "Hello parent" it means the child is killed before printing, and probably before signal. Try adding a sleep before kill and after signal (to avoid the child ending)

Comment: I have added `sleep(4)` both before the `kill()` and after `signal()`, the result is: `Hello parent` and `In child` without `Hello child`. The signal handler is stilled isn't called although the child is not terminated. Can you explain to me why?

Comment: @THẨMBùiĐình You still have a race condition where the child can exit before the signal is sent. Change the `sleep(4)` in the child to a `pause()` instead and see if that helps.

Comment: @Shawn OMG it works, but it takes so long, can I ask what is behind the installation of the signal() that takes it up to more than 4 secs?

Comment: I'm not sure what code you wrote but it doesn't take 4 seconds, I executed the code above (without any sleep or pause) and I get "Hello parent    Hello child   In child", it's probably just a matter of milliseconds. You simply need to make sure that signal is called before kill.